# Select equality expressions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I'm looking to select equality expressions in Rails, for simple possible-duplicate candidate detection.

Given the fields `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email` a query like the following would help identify possible duplicates:

```
SELECT id,
       -- Equality Expressions
       (first_name = :first_name) AS first_name_match,
       (last_name  = :last_name)  AS last_name_match,
       (email = :email)           AS email_match
FROM examples WHERE (id <> :id)
```

I've tried to do this using ActiveRecord as well as Arel but it appears you can't alias equality expressions in Arel.

I know this isn't the best performance method although I'm not expecting there to be enough records for the performance of this query to be an issue.

Is there a way I can build this query using ActiveRecord or Arel without using raw SQL?

Comment: You can use `CASE .. WHEN.. THEN`

Comment: I could, however as outlined I'm really looking to avoid writing raw SQL in my application, as I don't have any in it already so would like to avoid introducing it.

Comment: AR don't give all SQL luxury , and you can write the sql inside `.select('..')` method. I am not telling to write you pure SQL anyway. Arel is good, but there are time when it looks totally un readable too.